# Collect a particular attribute from all matching elements in selenium client?

Tags: xpath, selenium

I'm using selenium-client to test a site.  I want to get all a tags matching a particular selector, and then get the href attributes back in an array.  Can anyone tell me how i can do this?  For example, this returns the href of the first matching 'a' tag:

```
browser.get_attribute "//a[contains(@id,'friendImageLink')]/@href"
=> "http://asite/some-path"
```

Can i do the above and end up with an array of href strings?  It feels like it should be easy but i can't work it out :/  If i do this in firebug

```
$x("//a[contains(@id,'friendImageLink')]/@href")
```

I get an array of objects back, so it feels like i'm close.

thanks, max

EDIT - i thought of counting the matching elements and then iterating through them, but i can't seem to select the n'th element at all.  For example, the page in question has 38 a tags matching the "contains" condition, but if i do this

```
browser.get_attribute "//a[contains(@id,'friendImageLink')][2]/@href"
```

I get an error message saying 
Selenium::CommandError: OR: Element /descendant::a[contains(@id,'friendImageLink')][2]/ not found

EDIT - i just figured out a way.  `@browser.get_all_links` returns all the ids of all links on the page in an array.  I can then grep out the ones i want and iterate over the resulting filtered array, getting each link and then getting it's href.  eg

```
@browser.get_all_links.grep(/friendImageLink/).collect{|link_id| @browser.get_attribute("//a[@id='#{link_id}']/@href") }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is FAQ. This:

```
//a[contains(@id,'friendImageLink')][2]
```

Means: *Any `a` being the second `a` child having an attribute `id` containing `friendImageLink`*

**`//` operator has more precedence than predicate**

You need:

```
(//a[contains(@id,'friendImageLink')])[2]/@href
```

Comment: @Max Williams: You are wellcome.